# Talend MySql String To MySql Date for storage and difference calculations

Tags: mysql, parsing, date, talend

I have a MySql table with a String 2014-02-21 16:53:01 stored in a varchar column. I need to use Talend Data Integration to convert it into a date for calculations in the format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss and to store it in that format in another MySql as a date column after the calculations.

I have a talend tmap component but I get parsing errors and not sure how to solve it and the general sequence of steps needed.

In the tmap I have a variable with the expression

```
row1.date !=null ? TalendDate.parseDate("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss",row1.date):null
```

Which I hope will load the variable wiIs that the best way to

1. Convert the string in the source table to a date in the format I need?
2. How do you handle null dates as I need to get the difference between 2 dates but handle the situation where 1 or both may be blank or null
3. How do I get the destination table to store the date in the format I need? I have the Date Pattern supplied in the destination tmap schema but is that enough if the date format is yyyy-mm-dd ?

Any Talend experts able to help a novice out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better control on null check I recommend you to use below function.

```
!Relational.ISNULL(row1.date) && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(row1.date) ?TalendDate.parseDate("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm",row1.date):(null or default date);
```

if you are doing any operation on date? then don`t supply null as a result because you may get error on next component.

always pass default value so that you can check in next component and ignore it or store it based on business need.

Comment: So the normal way of working is to set a date I know won't appear in the data as a default date instead of null? Any common dates that people use or is there a limit how far back you should go?

Comment: If you ask me I use "1900-01-01" for minimum date and "9999-12-31" for max limit. So i can use date.before or after function to know whether it is default date or not

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify a few final things once the date is parsed by TalendDate.parseDate I can output it in any number of different ways by using the different formatting strings ? And is talend smart enough to store the date in the format specified in the schema or do I need to format it as well and the schema date format is just a final check?

Comment: Once you parse the date you will get Date object which can be parse in any format, or all the rules are valid which are applicable for java date. once date parse and db type is date then talend parse convert the date format suitable to db date format. mostly i generate metadata for outputs so that i don`t need to bother about date formats it derives from table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below condition which will take care of blank string also;-

row1.date !=null && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(row1.date)? TalendDate.parseDate("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm",row1.date) : null

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I decided to configure the schema for the database input to identify the dates as the date datatype instead of string which got Talend to do the work of converting

The pointers on validating the date were useful as well. Thanks for the help UmeshR